# Taking MYSQL query out of for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a query without using any sort of loop to get values from the database. I have an array $guest_list_guest_ids that stores all of the ids I would like to pull.

Not quite sure how I could accomplish this without a loop, where I would change the query every time based on the ID I'm parsing.

```
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM guest_list_guests' . implode(',', $guest_list_guest_ids);
    echo $query;
```

Any help or input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM guest_list_guests where id in (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you're using PDO, but should be adaptable to MySQLi:

```
// the frame of the query we're going to prepare
$query_frame = 'SELECT * FROM guest_list_guests WHERE id IN (%s);'

// generate a placeholder string, one for each element in the array of ids
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($guest_list_guest_ids), '?'));

// make the query string, eg: SELECT * FROM guest_list_guests WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?);
$query = sprintf($query_frame, $placeholders);

// prepare
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

// execute
$stmt->execute($guest_list_guest_ids);

// get results
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```